# How to Download File From FTPS Server In PHP?

Tags: php, file, ftp

I'm trying to download a file from an FTPS server in PHP using the ftp_fget function, but I'm encountering an error that I can't resolve.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_ssl_connect('ftps.test.com', 2222) or die("Could not connect to");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, 'user', 'pwd');
if ($login) {
    echo "Successfully logged in";
} else {
    echo "Log in failed";
}

$local_file = "test.txt";
$fp = fopen($local_file,"w");

//this is the path on server where file located
$rsr_product_file = 'keydealer/categories.txt';

// download server file and save it to open local file
if (ftp_fget($ftp_conn, $fp, $rsr_product_file, FTP_ASCII, 0)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
} else {
    echo "Error downloading $rsr_product_file.";
}
```

Upon execution, the script successfully logs into the server but fails when trying to download the file. Here's the output I'm receiving:

> Successfully logged in Warning: ftp_get(): Syntax error, command unrecognized in /chroot/home/test/test.y.net/html/pub/Newftp.php on line 35  Error downloading keydealer/categories.txt

The error message suggests that there's a syntax error or unrecognized command, but I can't figure out what's wrong. I suspect the issue lies somewhere in the ftp_fget function, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to resolve this issue?

Comment: The error says *"ftp_get"*, what does not match your code.

Comment: question corrected any help @MartinPrikryl ?